# How to build a dynamic object in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, angularjs, typescript, multidimensional-array

Hello I have the following problem, I want to form the following payload structure that is in the example of the first code paragraph, I was advancing well until I came across the part of the form that is dynamic and no matter how hard I try it has not worked out, I would appreciate it really much your help.

The problem is that I cannot build the structure as the first paragraph of code, especially in the dataCollege field, since it does not save the array dynamically.

I tried to put the FormControl in the html where I render the dynamic inputs but it gives me an error

This is the structure of the payload that I was able to assemble the first 3, but the last one is where I have a problem, which is the field datosCole, which is dynamic, depending on the GradosCole field, which can be initial, has 2 values, primary has 3 values and secondary has 4 values

```
{ name: Sara,
  age: 14, 
  gradeCollege: Secondary, 
  dataCollege: {         
                 course: "Maths",
                 schedule: "Afternoon",
                 section: "A",
                 teacher: "Mateo",
               }
}
```

This is my HTML sheet of how I build my form.

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="form">

<!-- Name -->
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Name" [formControl]="name">
</mat-form-field>

<!-- Age -->
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Age" [formControl]="age">
</mat-form-field>

<!-- Grade -->
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Grade</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="gradeCollege">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of grades" [value]="item" (click)="getData(item)">
      {{item}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<!-- dynamic data -->
<div *ngFor="let item of data; index as i" >
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [type]="item.type" [placeholder]="item.label" [formControl]="dataCollege" >
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

 </form>

  <div>
    <button type="button" (click)="save()">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my TS file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({ selector: 'app-datos', templateUrl: './datos.component.html', styleUrls: ['./datos.component.scss'] }) export class DatosComponent implements OnInit {

public grades: any[] = ['initial','primary','secondary']; 
public data: any[] = []

// Form 
public form: FormGroup; 
public name: AbstractControl; 
public age: AbstractControl; 
public gradeCollege: AbstractControl; 
public dataCollege: AbstractControl;

constructor( protected fb: FormBuilder, ) {

}

ngOnInit() {
 this.form = this.fb.group({ 
             name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])], 
             age: [''], 
             gradeCollege: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])], 
             dataCollege:  ['']
}); 

this.name= this.form.get('name');
this.age = this.form.get('age');
this.gradeCollege = this.form.get('gradeCollege');
this.dataCollege = this.form.get('dataCollege'); }

getData (typeGrade: any) {

console.log(typeGrade);

if(typeGrade === 'initial'){
  this.data = null
  this.data = [
    {type: 'text', label: 'course'},
    {type: 'text', label: 'schedule'},
  ]
}

if(typeGrade === 'primary'){
  this.data = null
  this.data = [
    {type: 'text', label: 'course'},
    {type: 'text', label: 'schedule'},
    {type: 'text', label: 'section'}
  ]
}

if(typeGrade === 'secondary'){
  this.data= null
  this.data = [
    {type: 'text', label: 'course'},
    {type: 'text', label: 'schedule'},
    {type: 'text', label: 'section'},
    {type: 'text', label: 'teacher'}
  ]
}

}

submit() {
 const payload = {
  name: this.name.value,
  age: this.age.value,
  gradeCollege: this.gradeCollege.value,
  dataCollege: this.dataCollege.value,
 };

 console.log(payload)

}}
```

this is the error

> ERROR TypeError: ctx.save is not a function
> at ActionDialogComponent_Template_button_click_13_listener (template.html:34:36)
> at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:21860:1)
> at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:21902:1)
> at HTMLButtonElement. (platform-browser.js:976:1)
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399:1)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41686:1)
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398:1)
> at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167:1)
> at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:480:1)
> at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621:1)
> defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6241
> handleError @ core.js:6294
> handleError @ core.js:13881
> executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.js:21863
> wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.js:21902
> (anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:976
> invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:399
> onInvokeTask @ core.js:41686
> invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:398
> runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:167
> invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:480
> invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1621
> globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1647

Comment: You haven't stated what your issue is.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot build the structure as the first paragraph of code, especially in the dataCollege field, since it does not save the array dynamically.

I tried to put the FormControl in the html where I render the dynamic inputs but it gives me an error

Comment: @Daniel What kind of error are you getting? Can you update your question to include the error?

Also, I am not sure if these are typos, but you missed a closing bracket for `ngOnInit`, and the `getData` function is spelled as `getDatos` in your TS file.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you want that the "dataCollege" is an Array, not an object.

Some like, e.g.

```
{ name: Sara,
  age: 14, 
  gradeCollege: Secondary, 
  dataCollege:[{         
                 course: "Maths",
                 schedule: "Afternoon",
                 section: "A",
                 teacher: "Mateo",
               }
              ]
  }
```

or if you has two elements

```
{ name: Sara,
  age: 14, 
  gradeCollege: Secondary, 
  dataCollege:[{         
                 course: "Maths",
                 schedule: "Afternoon",
                 section: "A",
                 teacher: "Mateo",
               },
{         
                 course: "Language",
                 schedule: "Afternoon",
                 section: "C",
                 teacher: "Alex",
               }
              ]
  }
```

Well you has an array of objects, so you should use an FormArray of FormGroups

A FormArray of FormGroup as mannage always in the same way

1.-Declare in a .ts a getter of your formArray

```
get dataCollege()
{
    return this.form.get('dataCollege') as FormArray
}
```

2.- in .html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   ...inputs thats belog to the main form in the way,e.g...
   ..see that you use formControlName="control-name"
   ..the control-name between quotes but the "formControlName" as is..

     <input formControlName="name">
       ....
   ..a div with formArrayName..
   <div formArrayName="dataCollege">

      ..a ngFor to iterate over the formArray.controls.. 
      ..you use the "getter" defined in the fisrt step..
      ..you add [formGroupName]="i"..

      <div *ngFor="let group of dataCollege.controls;let i=index"
                  [formGroupName]="i"

          ..like in the main group you use formControlName for the...
          ..controls of the FormArray...,e.g.

          <input formControlName="course">

      </div>
   </div>
```

And forget all your getters to get the control